# Why can't I set a Transformer to a LazyList in Apache Commons?

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons

In apache.commons.collections there is a class called [MapUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MapUtils.html) which have these two methods to define a Map which can create on demand objects for the map:

- [lazyMap(Map,Factory)](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MapUtils.html#lazyMap%28java.util.Map,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Factory%29)
- [lazyMap(Map,Transformer)](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MapUtils.html#lazyMap%28java.util.Map,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer%29)

So I can use a factory to instantiate the object

```
Factory factory = new Factory() {
    public Object create() {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

or a transformer to instantiate the new object depending on the key of the map

```
Transformer factory = new Transformer() {
    public Object transform(Object mapKey) {
        return new Object(mapKey);
    }
}
```

There's a similar class for Lists: [ListUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html), but this class only has a method with a Factory:

- [lazyList(List list, Factory factory)](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#lazyList%28java.util.List,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Factory%29)

I'd like to transform the object like in the map situation but using the index of the object in the list instead of the key in the map.

```
Transformer factory = new Transformer() {
    public Object transform(int index) {
        return new Object(index);
    }
}
```

My question is why there is not a lazyList(List list, Transformer transformer)? Does apache provide any other List to do this or do I have to build my custom implementation?

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't there because it was never implemented. You'll just have to work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in my opinion you should use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for this sort of thing... it makes full use of generics and provides a much more well thought-out, compact and sensible API. It also provides a [Lists.transform](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method which transforms an underlying `List` based on the *elements* at each position in the list.

That said, I don't think a transform method for transforming a `List` by *index* makes much sense. The actual underlying `List` would be completely meaningless given that the transformation would ignore the elements it contains... only its size would matter. Could you explain why you would want to do something like that?

Comment: I think List.transform doesn't fit my needs. I want to use the index where the object is inserted to create the object because I'm creating an iterative structure which depends on the index. List.transform allows to transform the object before adding it, but the transform function is not aware of the index. I'll write my own implementation. thanks anyway.